# Is it possible to run something before DOMContentLoaded?

Tags: events, firefox, firefox-addon

I want to inject stylesheets and scripts before `DOMContentLoaded`.

In Google Chrome it is possible using [`run_at = document_start`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html).

Is there something similar in Firefox addons? Can I run things before `gBrowser.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded"` ? How?

Comment: Do you want to inject the stylesheets only in specific pages? If not, you can use the stylesheet service to make them globally available to all sites.

Comment: @Felix I need on a specific website...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current workaround I'm using is the following

```
gBrowser.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted",
    function (e)
    {
        if (typeof(e.relatedNode.tagName) != "undefined" &&
            e.relatedNode.tagName == "DIV")
        {
            var window = e.relatedNode.ownerDocument.defaultView;
            if (window.MyScript) return; // if it was injected
                                         // ignore other events
            if (/siteregex/i.test(window.location.href))
            {
                Initialize(window); // inject scripts
            }
        }
    },
    true);
```

`DIV` is the first element on `body`, so it will load right after this node. I won't have to wait for the whole page.